# How do I run IntelliJ with the right version of Java and Gradle when importing a project?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I'm being able to run my intelliJ properly, but when I try to import my gradle project it shows this message:

```
Gradle 3.5 requires Java 7 or later to run.You are currently using Java 6.
```

The thing is if I run java -version I get this:

```
java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)
```

And gradle -version I get this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.0
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2017-06-14 15:11:08 UTC
Revision:     316546a5fcb4e2dfe1d6aa0b73a4e09e8cecb5a5

Groovy:       2.4.11
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
JVM:          1.8.0_60 (Oracle Corporation 25.60-b23)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.10.2 x86_64
```

If I try running IntelliJ from the command Line I can see this on my console:

```
[   5891]  ERROR -    #com.intellij.lang.Language - IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4  Build #IU-141.1532.4 
[   5891]  ERROR -    #com.intellij.lang.Language - JDK: 1.6.0_65 
[   5891]  ERROR -    #com.intellij.lang.Language - VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 
[   5891]  ERROR -    #com.intellij.lang.Language - Vendor: Apple Inc. 
[   5891]  ERROR -    #com.intellij.lang.Language - OS: Mac OS X
```

How do I modify the JDK that runs the IntelliJ?
If I try to set the jdk and gradle when importing the project I'm still getting the same error.

Thank you!

Comment: File > Project Structure > Project > Project SDK

Comment: It's not that... I can't even open the project. So when I open the IntelliJ, I click on Import project and I'm not able to finalize importing it. So I can't see this path...

Comment: Seems to be the JDK version that is running the IntelliJ that is the problem...

Comment: Weird... haven't heard of that issue before. To be fair, I've only run Intellij on Win/Linux, but it shouldn't really matter. Check the Mac settings?

Comment: Your IntelliJ IDEA is very old, in the current versions Gradle JVM [can be specified separately](http://i.imgur.com/lLRsXUw.png) from the JVM used to run IntelliJ IDEA or the project JVM.

Comment: On my Mac settings it's showing Java 7, so it shouldn't be causing that problem... I don't know where it's using this Java 6

Comment: I'll try to download the latest version here and see how it goes.. Thank you

Comment: I'm still getting an error even with the latest version... Invalid Gradle JDK configuration found. Open Gradle Settings
JAVA_HOME environment variable not defined.